# Why the hotkey ^#{Left}:: is invalid?

Tags: autohotkey

I'm just starting with AHK so maybe this looks like a dumb question to you...

I'm trying to trigger a script to the hotkey **^#{Left}::** and the IDE 'AHK Studio' is warning me that this hotkey is invalid.

PS. My OS is Windows 10 pro

Thanks

Comment: Key names are enclosed in braces only in special cases such as the send command. To define a hotkey use them without braces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As user3419297 mentioned:

You only enclose Buttons (such as `Left`) in curly braces `{}` when you are using something like a send command (such as `Send ^#{Left}`)

However, when defining a hotkey, you should omit these braces (i.e. instead of `^#{Left}::script` use `^#Left::script`.